# How to create a map of strings from map[string]interface{}?

Tags: go

Noob gopher here. 
I'd like to fill data into this struct field:

```
userData map[string]interface{}
```

The data is like:

```
ud := map[string]string{"userName": "noob"}
```

but I get this comple time error:

> cannot use ud (type map[string]string) as type map[string]interface {}
>   in field value

I also tried:

```
ud := map[string]interface{"userName": "noob".(string)}
```

but this gives:

> syntax error: unexpected string literal

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks good guys on [gopher slack](https://gophers.slack.com/), I realized what was wrong. 
Basically I just missed {} of the interface, like this:

```
ud := map[string]interface{}{"userName": "noob"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can do like this

```
ud := make(map[string]interface{})
ud["userName"] = "noob"
```